# MacOS Pyside2 QSystemTrayIcon, left click/right different functions

Tags: python, macos, pyside2, qsystemtrayicon

I would like to know how to do in python/Pyside2:

Create a QSystemTrayIcon with a custom icon, in which:

- If I click left button on it, I do a custom action (just print “left click pressed”). No menu should be shown...
- If I click right button on it, a context menu appears with an exit action on it, just to close the program.

On **MacOS**, maybe not in win nor linux, **the menu just opens on mouse press**... That's why the need of left and right click differentiations
otherwise both actions will be done with left and right click. See note here: [On macOS... since the menu opens on mouse press](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QSystemTrayIcon.html)

I need help just implementing the left and right click differentiations in the following code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import sys

class SystrayLauncher(object):

    def __init__(self):
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget() #just to get the style(), haven't seen other way
        icon = w.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxInformation)
        self.tray = QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.tray.setIcon(icon)
        self.tray.setVisible(True)
        self.tray.activated.connect(self.customAction)

        # I JUST WANT TO SEE THE MENU WHEN RIGHT CLICK...
        self.trayIconMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        self.quitAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Quit", None, triggered=QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().quit)
        self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.quitAction)
        self.tray.setContextMenu(self.trayIconMenu)

    # JUST WANNA USE THE ACTION WITH LEFT CLICK
    def customAction(self, signal):
        print "left click pressed"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    sl = SystrayLauncher()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

you can differentiate the click "reason" and decide what to do. Therefore you will need to add a function like follows:

```
def right_or_left_click(reason):
    if reason == QSystemTrayIcon.ActivationReason.Trigger:
        print("Left-click detected")
    elif reason == QSystemTrayIcon.ActivationReason.Context:
        print("Right-click detected")
    elif reason == QSystemTrayIcon.ActivationReason.MiddleClick:
        print("Middle-click detected")
    else:
        print("Unknown reason")

self.tray.activated.connect(right_or_left_click)
```

Then, you can call the desired function on left-click or middle-click. The right-click is occupied by your context menu :)

Comment: This will still show the context menu on left or middle click. How do I prevent the context menu in these cases?